# Galois extension definition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory, definition

Let $L,K$ be fields with $L/K$ a field extension. We say $L/K$ is a Galois extension if $L/K$ is normal and separable.

I don't fully understand this definition, is it saying that

1) $L$ has to be the splitting field for some polynomial in $K[x]$ and that polynomial must not have any repeated roots, or is it saying that

2) $L$ has to be the splitting field for *all* polynomials in $K[x]$ and all polynomials must not have repeated roots?

Comment: Why the downvote? I have a valid question on a definition I don't understand I gave the definition and my intepretation in two possible ways for someone to clarify I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It's definitely not $2)$ since that would be the algebraic closure

Comment: So is it $1)$ or even close to $1)$

Comment: 1) is correct (or, equivalent to some other possible definitions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We *define* a Galois extension $L/K$ to be an extension of fields that is

1. **Normal**: if $x\in L$ has minimal polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$, and $y$ is another root of $f$, then $y\in L$.
2. **Separable**: if $x\in L$ has minimal polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$, then $f$ has distinct roots in its splitting field.

When $L/K$ is a finite extension, these conditions are *equivalent* to $L$ being the splitting field of a separable polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$ - i.e. your condition $1$. This is a fact which is proven in any course in Galois theory. See for example Theorem 3.10 in [these lecture notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf).

Your condition $2$ is certainly false: for example $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)/\mathbb Q$ is a Galois extension, but is not the splitting field of $X^5+3X+2$ or of any other (irreducible) polynomial other than $X^2-2$.

Comment: whqt hapens in the infinite case

Comment: @m.idaya The splitting field of a polynomial is always finite, so it wouldn't make sense to define an infinite Galois extension to be a splitting field. However, the notions of being normal and separable make perfect sense for infinite extensions.

Comment: the hypothese for th  question  is L/K galoisienne and not specifie finite or infinite

Answer (score 1):

A definition is a definition ! Anyway, **Roughly speaking** , it is saying that $$Gal(L/K)=Aut_K(L)$$
and thus that $Gal(L/K)$ is indeed a group and that $|Gal(L/K)|=[L:K]$. Indeed, if it's just separable, then $Gal(L/K)$ would be $Hom_K(L,K^{alg})$ what is not a group. And if it's only normal, then $$|Aut_K(L)|=|Gal(L/K)|<[L:K].$$

So, finally, since we want that $Gal(L/K)$ be a group (i.e. $Gal(L/K)=Aut_K(L)$,) and that $$|Gal(L/K)|=[L:K],$$
we need to defined $L/K$ as separable and normal. It's thanks to those properties that the correspondance between the (complete) lattice of groups and (complete) lattice of fields make sense.

Comment: So which (or neither) of my thinking 1) or 2) is correct?

Comment: case finite extension to1) and not to 2). in the infinite case no equivalence are there to 1) and also to 2).  sorry for my englisch and thanks

Answer (score 1):

A separable algebraic extension field $L/K$ is one where given any element $\alpha \in L$, the minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha}(x) \in K[x]$ is separable (that is, has distinct roots in some extension of $K$).

For the most part, the fields one commonly encounters, such as $\Bbb Q, \Bbb R, \Bbb C$ and $\Bbb Z_p$, are separable (these fields are *perfect fields*, and any finite extension is separable).

In fact, it is not immediately apparent that there are *any* non-separable fields, so this is the most commonly-given example:

Let $K = \Bbb Z_2(t)$ (this is the field of quotients of the integral domain  $\Bbb Z_2[t]$). Consider the polynomial $x^2 - t \in K[x]$, to which we can assign the splitting field $L = K(\sqrt{t})$. $x^2 - t$ splits in $L$ as $(x - \sqrt{t})^2$ (here we are taking advantage of the fact that $\text{char}(\Bbb Z_2(t)) = 2$). I leave it to you to show $x^2 - t$ is indeed irreducible in $K[x]$ (hint: show we cannot have $t = \dfrac{p(t)^2}{q(t)^2}$ for any $p,q \in \Bbb Z_2[t]$).

In short, your first characterization is better, a separable extension need not be the splitting field for *all* separable polynomials in $K[x]$.

Normality is a different condition, essentially expressing "how fully" an extension splits an irreducible polynomial. For example, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$ is $x^3 - 2$.

However, $x^3 - 2$ does not split fully in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, but only splits this far:

$x^3 - 2 = (x - \sqrt[3]{2})(x^2 + \sqrt[3]{2}x + \sqrt[3]{4})$,

consequently $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not a normal extension of $\Bbb Q$.

It turns out that for finite extensions there is a one-to-one correspondence between the subfields of $L$ containing $K$ and the subgroups of $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ precisely when $L$ is Galois over $K$ (this is called, surprisingly enough, the *Galois correspondence*), and that the normal subgroups of $\text{Aut}(L/K)$ then correspond to the normal extension fields of $K$ contained in $L$.

Answer (score 0):

the extension $L/K$ is galoisien is equivalently to each $x\in L$, 
$x$ is algebraic over $K$ and the minimal polynomial of $x$ has
simple roots and are all in $L$. so by primitive element theorem
we get: the extension $L/K$  finite and  galoisienne is equivalent
to your proposal 1) but not to 2).

but in the infinity case; $L/K$ galoisienne  is not equivalent
either to 1) or 2)

Answer (score 0):

The simpler answer is that your definition (1) is correct in the case $[L:K] < \infty$.

But let me give a better (generalizable) definition.

Suppose $K \subset L$ is a field extension.  Then $L$ is said to be Galois over $K$ if   $L^G=K$ where $G=Aut_K(L)$ and $L^G=\lbrace x\in L\mid \sigma(x)=x \ \forall \ \sigma\in G \rbrace$.

This definition implies your definition (1) in the case $[L:K]< \infty$.  How?

**Assuming this definition**, if $\alpha\in L$ such that $f(X)\in K[X]$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, we need to show that $f(X)$ has distinct roots in $L$. Observe that each of $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root of $f(X)$ since $\sigma$ fixes $K$.

Thus, the set $T_{\alpha}=\lbrace\sigma(\alpha) \mid \sigma \in G\rbrace$ is finite. 
So we may as well write $T_{\alpha}=\lbrace \sigma_i(\alpha) \in G\mid 1\leq i\leq k \rbrace$ for some positive integer $k$ and $\sigma_i(\alpha)\neq \sigma_j(\alpha)$ for $i\neq j$.

Consider the polynomial $g(X)=\prod_{\sigma(\alpha)\in T_{\alpha}}(X-\sigma(\alpha))\in L[X]$.  Observe that $\tau(g(X))=g(X)$ for each $\tau\in G$, where the $\tau$ acts on the coefficients of $g(X)$ and leaves $X$ unchanged.  But then our definition of Galois extension implies that $g(X)\in K[X]$.

By minimality of $f(X)$ we deduce that $f(X)$ divides $g(X)$.  Also, since each $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is a root of $f(X)$, we deduce that $(X-\sigma_i(\alpha))$ divides $f(X)$ in $L[X]$.   And hence $g(X)\mid f(X)$ in $L[X]$.  It is not hard to digest that $g(X) \mid f(X)$ in $K[X]$.

Thus, $f(X)=g(X)$.   Then $g(X)$ has distinct roots by definition and thus $f(X)$ is separable.

Thus, we have shown that every element $\alpha\in L$ is separable.  Using primitive element theorem, we get $L=K(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda \in L$. Let $F(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$.  By above calculation, we observe that $F(X)$ splits in $L$ and  in any field $M$ in which $F(X)$ splits must contain $\alpha$ and its conjugates.  Thus, $L$ is the splitting field of $F(X)$.

**On the other hand**, if $L$ was splitting field of $f(X)\in K[X]$. Then it is not hard to show that the Galois group $G$ acts transitively on the roots of any minimal polynomial $g(X)$ of an element $\beta$ in $L$. (It is an argument involving extension of field automorphisms). Thus, if all of Galois group fixes and element $\beta\in L$, it is forced that the minimal polynomial be of degree $1$ and hence we get $L^G=K$.

Comment: Is definition 1 implies definition that you gave?